# @discardableResult is not working as expected in framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I have met with a strange issue in my framework project. The Swift 3 compiler is warning me of an *unused result* when I try to call a function in my framework, even though I have marked the function in framework with `@discardableResult`

Here is my code
`SampleFramework.swift` file in my `cocoa touch framework` project

```
import Foundation

@discardableResult
public func keychainPerform(key:String) -> String{
    print("success");
    return "aaa";
}
```

`ViewController.swift` file in `single view application` swift project

```
import UIKit
import SampleFramework

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        SampleFramework.keychainPerform(key: "asd") //  Warning: result of call is unused
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

I checked the scenario with other frameworks but `@discardableResult` is working perfectly on all of them, so please help me to find out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try `let _ = SampleFramework.keychainPerform(key: "asd")`  if you just want to remove warning.

Comment: No, I don't want my framework users to suppress this warning like this

Comment: Does this work with Swift 4?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm seeing similar behavior in a framework.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over the very same problem in Xcode 12 / Swift 5.3.

I think this is a bug in the compiler with regards to interface file caching.

If you had the function previously created without the `@discardableResult` attribute, the compiler obviously does not pick it up after adding unless you do a full rebuild, i.e. force cleaning the build folder and/or delete the `DerivedData`.